# slow loading in sqlite

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite

I have a Data base  in sqlite 3.and .exe file witch was write with C# 2010.My .EXE file call DB.but when I write this files to DVD or put it to virtual drive,my program load very slowly(at least 2 min),How can I solve this Problem?

Answer (score 2):

Random accesses on DVDs are slow.

You should copy the entire database file into a temporary directory on disk (or into a memory database).

Comment: plz show me in example.